# \noindent before command not working

Tags: indentation

I would like to suppress the indentation of text with `\noindent`. However, I am finding that using `\noindent` in front of a command is not working as I had expected and I do not understand why.

Here is a minimal working example showing my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\InsertTextA}{
  This is some text.
}

\newcommand{\InsertTextB}{
  \noindent This is some text.
}

\begin{document}

This is some text. % Indented, as expected

\noindent This is some text. % Not indented, as expected

\InsertTextA{} % Indented, as expected

\noindent\InsertTextA{} % Why is this line still "somewhat" indented?

\InsertTextB{} % Not indented, as expected

\end{document}
```

The line `\noindent\InsertTextA{}` appears still somewhat indented:

[image]

How do I make `\noindent` work in this case?

Comment: you are adding spaces, but why use `\noindent` at all, it should not be needed in latex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\InsertTextA}{%
  This is some text.
}

\newcommand{\InsertTextB}{%
  \noindent This is some text.
}

\begin{document}

This is some text. % Indented, as expected

\noindent This is some text. % Not indented, as expected

\InsertTextA{} % Indented, as expected

\noindent\InsertTextA{}

\InsertTextB{} % Not indented, as expected

\end{document}
```

Add a comment symbol `%` to prevent the space character from sneaking into tex stomach.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is here already, I add an answer of this part of your question: "I do not understand why".

Your macros `\InsertTextA` and `\InsertTetxB` expand to `space` (tokenized from the end of the line) followed by `This is some text.` (or `\noindent` followed by `This is some text.`) followed by `space` (tokenized from the end of the line).

The token processor of TeX generates space at the end of lines and it generates `\par` at the empty lines. TeX is in vertical mode after `\par`. The space in the vertical mode is ignored. The `\noindent` is TeX primitive which starts horizontal mode without indentation. The space in horizontal mode is not ignored.

Your line in the document:

```
\noindent\InsertTextA{} % Why is this line still "somewhat" indented?
```

does `\noindent` from document, `space` from macro, `This is some text.`, `space` (the last one from the macro), `open group`, `close group` (they are from your `{}` which is irrelevant code in your document), `space` (before percent character). The first `\noindent` opens horizontal mode, so the following space is printed. The following empty line generates `\par`, it removes single last space from horizontal list and creates the paragraph. The second last space remains in the paragraph, but you don't see it because the paragraph is finished by `\parfillskip`, i.e. TeX glue to the right margin of the document.

On the other hand, your line

```
\InsertTextB{} % Not indented, as expected
```

does `space` from your macro, it is ignored because TeX is in vertical mode, then `\noindent` opens horizontal mode, `This is some text.` is printed in horizontal mode, `space` is added, `open group`, `close group` does nothing, `space` (before percent character). The `\par` from following empty line removes the last space and generates the paragraph from the material accumulated in horizontal mode.

The double space at the end of your paragraphs is second potential problem, because `\par` removes only the last one. You have single space here if you don't write redundant code `{}` because then the end of the line is at the end of the control sequence `\InsertTextB` and token processor doesn't generate space in such case.

If you are creating TeX macros, you must understand token processor principles, horizontal/vertical mode switching, TeX glues, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation! I really appreciate it and definitely learned a lot!